# Get text from a string knowing its position?

Tags: ruby, json, string

I get the source-code of an HTML page and put it in a string.

What I want to do is get the "parameters" of a JavaScript function that resides in the source code different times. I want to get the first result.

This is an example of the function where `?` represents the characters of the text I want to get:

```
asdf({"id":?????,"uid":"?????","user":{"username":"?????","permalink":"?????"}});
```

How can I get the string after `"uid":` in `"uid":"????"` when the `"?"` strings have variable length and characters?

For example, I want to get the text `eD9od0fopdh5` from this string knowing it's after the text `"uid":`.

```
asdf({"id":128999175,"uid":"eD9od0fopdh5","user":{"username":"sportshistory","permalink":"sportshistory"}})
```

Comment: Are all values of "X" the same? Or is it more like `window.push({"id":A,"uid":"B","user":{"username":"C","permalink":"D"}});`?

Comment: 1sec,installing ruby now

Comment: all Xs are different and all have different lenght

Comment: I see no code, so I have to guess you haven't written anything. We'd like to see that you've put some effort into answering your question before we jump in and solve it for you. That's the Stack Overflow way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go at it this way:

```
require 'json'

str = 'asdf({"id":128999175,"uid":"eD9od0fopdh5","user":{"username":"sportshistory","permalink":"sportshistory"}})'
data = str[/\((.+)\)/, 1]
# => "{\"id\":128999175,\"uid\":\"eD9od0fopdh5\",\"user\":{\"username\":\"sportshistory\",\"permalink\":\"sportshistory\"}}"

params = JSON.parse(data)
# => {"id"=>128999175,
#     "uid"=>"eD9od0fopdh5",
#     "user"=>{"username"=>"sportshistory", "permalink"=>"sportshistory"}}

params['uid'] # => "eD9od0fopdh5"
```

That'll get it for you.

If you want to change it:

```
params['uid'] = 'foo'

params # => {"id"=>128999175, "uid"=>"foo", "user"=>{"username"=>"sportshistory", "permalink"=>"sportshistory"}}
```

And if you want it as JSON again:

```
params.to_json # => "{\"id\":128999175,\"uid\":\"foo\",\"user\":{\"username\":\"sportshistory\",\"permalink\":\"sportshistory\"}}"
```

The reason I use `data = str[/\((.+)\)/, 1]` is it'll forgive changes in the size of the parameters, or their order. As long as the data is contained within the parameter of the JavaScript function the pattern will pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the JSON hash as a string in *ruby*, when you don't want to use any external gem, you shell get `uid` as follows:

```
string = 'asdf({"id":128999175,"uid":"eD9od0fopdh5","user":{"username":"sportshistory","p‌​ermalink":"sportshistory"}})'
uid = string =~ /"uid":"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/ && $1
"eD9od0fopdh5"
```

Comment: window.push({"id":X,"uid":"X","user":{"username":"X","permalink":"X"}}); is the text I'm trying to find and from which I have to get the varables Xs

Comment: @user1677678 from which? I've updated the answer, you just have to set up the X variable properly, to select a value (with `'uid' == X` for the `window` array.

Comment: @user1677678 some additional =)

Comment: @user1677678 i see, but you need to explain in which case `X` is variable, and in which "X" is "X". I see in your condition that `'uid'=='X'` not `X`

Comment: reedited the question adding and example of what I want it to do

Comment: @user1677678 it seems that you what to do it not in *ruby*, but in *js*, am I right?

Comment: sorry, I think I didn't explain the problem really well, I edited the question again.

Comment: @user1677678 what is the `asdf` in your example? I see the code that close in `{}` is the hash. What did you do with it? the value of key uid can be easily get with code: `hash[ 'uid'] # => eD9od0fopdh5`

Comment: @user1677678 we can chat =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45150/discussion-between-user1677678-and-majioa)

Comment: @user1677678 I've updated the answer, have you a question yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a hash from the json

```
require 'json'

str= 'window.push({"id":"X","uid":"X","user":{"username":"X","permalink":"X"}});'
json_str= str[12..-3]
p json_str
hash= JSON.parse(json_str)
p hash['uid']
```